# MySQL selects rows from a table based on a field's relationship with a limit from a field value

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in MYSQL database, **table1** has fields: **ID, ServiceID, Patients**

Like following,

```
ID | ServiceID | Patients  
1  | Item 2    | 2
2  | Item 3    | 1
3  | Item 1    | 2
```

Which ServiceID is a **unique** Value,

**Table2** fields : **ID, ServiceID**

Like that

```
ID | ServiceID 
1  | Item 1    
2  | Item 3   
3  | Item 1    
4  | Item 2  
5  | Item 2  
6  | Item 1  
7  | Item 2
```

Which ServiceID is **not a unique** Value, and this table has a lot of rows
- ordered by ID

**table2** joining with **table1** By column **ServiceID**

I need to Reorder **table2** after select all rows in both tables but :

- After specifying the first row of **table1** rows, take the value 2 in the **ServiceID** field and search for it in **table2** by the number of times the value in the **Patients** field is 2 and then go back to **table1** for the next row and do the same thing, and after reaching the end of **table1** the number of rows in **table2** will not end and so I implement The same orders return to the first row in **table1**, and so on, so that the shape becomes as follows :

```
    ID | ServiceID 
    1  | Item 2
    2  | Item 2
    3  | Item 3
    4  | Item 1
    5  | Item 1
    6  | Item 2
    7  | Item 1
```

Thank you

Comment: Just curious, If serviceid is unique, why isn't it primary?

Comment: Because this field I do not use as a primary key for this table, but it is a value in relation with primary key of another table, and in this table the value for this field will not be repeated, so that i created as unique

Comment: I don't understand how ids suddenly become related to other serviceids